# Where to put property calculation in an MVC design

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, model

I'm building an application that manages holidays and absences from work using MVC patterns.

model

- Data layer - the properties of an absence
- Domain layer - load all the absences for an employee for a period
- Service layer - interacts with the domain layer and manipulate absence entities

I need to calculate the amount of holiday time used and available. Logically I'd do this in the service layer, that is get all the absences from the domain and iterate through them to get a result.

In the view I need to display all the absences and holidays used. This implies the system is loading the absences twice, once to calculate holiday usage and once to get a list to display.

Is this aright? In a non MVC but OOP world I would have an `AbsenceList` class with a `getHolidayUse()` method so the class would only need to be loaded from the database once.

Should I just accept that I'll need to load and destroy entities a lot and implement caching to cope with it?

Should I implement an `AbsenceList` entity that includes the list of absences and has a `holidayUsed` property that is calculated in the domain layer `findAll()` method?

Comment: I don't know the answer for a *correct* use of MVC, but I happen to be working on a project that someone else started which is MVC and we have a similar calculation ("Funds available" rather than "Holiday available") and we do it in the client-side javascript.  The total allowed and the future-promised are pulled via AJAX requests to the Controller and then the remaining calculated on the client (that is, in the View).

Comment: In MVC that would be implementing buisness logic in the view... which I think is a no no... but if it works.

Comment: The value is being displayed to the user as an information value in a disabled field.  The value of the field is never sent back to the model.  So in some respect, I agree with @Horaland, hence why my comment was not posted as an answer, but I wasn't the one to write the code.